# ListView on kill focus in mfc

Tags: c++, listview, mfc

I have a list view in a dialog. When I select some item inside list it's become selected. When I kill focus from list (for example, clicked at another window), the selection disappears. How to make it grayed(inactive) but leave in list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a style called `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS`.
Set it at runtime using:

```
DWORD dwStyle = m_list.GetExtendedStyle();
dwStyle |= LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS;
m_list.SetExtendedStyle(dwStyle);
```